# system and reserved folder 550GB win 10

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10

I am facing a big problem in my storage.

I have a hp laptop 1Tb HDD I found that my storage is shrinking so I tried to recover my system but with keeping my files but the same problem.

I used wizTree software and found that a folder called $extend is 550Gb

[image: $extend]

[image: system and reserved folder]

Comment: Every single folder, shown in the screenshot, is 0 bytes.  That folder should not be deleted, if you delete it, Windows will stop functioning.

Answer (score 0):

#### I found that a folder called `$Extend` is 550Gb

`$Extend` is a system reserved folder used by NTFS v3.0 or later. These files are required by the OS and should not be deleted.

> `$Extend` - A file system directory containing various optional extensions, such as `$Quota`, `$ObjId`, `$Reparse` or `$UsnJrnl`.

...

> v3.0: Released with Windows 2000. Supports disk quotas, Encrypting File System, sparse files, reparse points, update sequence number (USN) journaling, the **$Extend** folder and its files. Reorganized security descriptors so that multiple files using the same security setting can share the same descriptor. Commonly called NTFS 5.0 after the OS release.

Source [NTFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS)

Comment: but to use 550 GB I think there is problem